# Python: Plotting a regular grid of data in a latitude longitude grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contourf

I have a grid of data points with a value of latitude/longitude for each row/column. I want to plot this to give a nice looking map. How do I go about this? I have tried converting the latitude/longitude row/column 'titles' to cartesian but cant get this to work.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

general_file = 'data\ir2_20160815_114117_232_l3b_v10.nc'
file_data = Dataset(general_file)

lat = file_data.variables['latitude']
lon = file_data.variables['longitude']
rad = file_data.variables['radiance']

latitudes = lat[:]
longitudes = lon[:]
radiances = rad[0]

x= longitudes
y=latitudes
z = radiances

plt.contourf(x, y, z,25,cmap='Greys')
plt.title(general_file)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The data file was downloaded from https://darts.isas.jaxa.jp/pub/pds3/extras/vco_ir2_l3_v1.0/vcoir2_7001/data/l3b/netcdf/r0024/

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using my package ncplot (https://pypi.org/project/ncplot/).

```
import ncplot
ncplot.view('data\ir2_20160815_114117_232_l3b_v10.nc', "radiance")
```